# What is the sigificance of 0 in the parameters--String message=new String(recievepacket.getData(),0,recievepacket.getLength());

Tags: java, networking

If I use any other number instead of 0, I am not able to see any message. Why to use 0 while converting the received packet to string?

```
public class UdpClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatagramSocket cs=new DatagramSocket();
    byte [] recievedata=new byte[512];
    String message=null;
    byte [] senddata=new byte[512];
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("client created");
    InetAddress addr=InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    int port=9003;

    while(true) {

        System.out.println( "client says");
        message=br.readLine();

        senddata=message.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendpacket=new DatagramPacket(senddata, senddata.length, addr, port);
cs.send(sendpacket);        

DatagramPacket recievepacket=new DatagramPacket(recievedata, recievedata.length);
cs.receive(recievepacket);
message=new String(recievepacket.getData(), 0,recievepacket.getLength());
System.out.println("server says"+message);

    }

}
 }
```

Comment: Share your code......Sample

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: I assume you want to use all the data from the start and not ignore any of the first bytes, so you need to start at the `[0]` byte.

Comment: Did you try checking the documentation of String constructors? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: Shared the code. @SyedHamzaHassan

Comment: new String(recievepacket.getData(), 0,recievepacket.getLength());
here "0" is the starting place where you want to get your string i.e
If your string is  "Code" and you set it 1 then it will return "ode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)) of **String** class:

```
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)

Parameters:
bytes - The bytes to be decoded into characters
offset - The index of the first byte to decode
length - The number of bytes to decode
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Javadoc for String class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

The original method of String

```
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)

Parameters:
bytes - The bytes to be decoded into characters
offset - The index of the first byte to decode
length - The number of bytes to decode
```